# How to write source code/some characters in SO?

Tags: discussion, source-code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

As the following, '<' or <--' doesn't show with pre tag.
Is there any better way to write code in SO?

```
# Sample code from Programing Ruby, page 24
class Song
  def to_s # "
  end
end

song = Songson.new()
p song
```

Comment: Actually, yes, there is a better way. Edit this question, place your cursor in the body, and look at the editing help on the right; it should tell you how to format code. (And as a bonus, it gets syntax highlighting also.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes:

```
# Sample code from Programing Ruby, page 24
class Song
  def to_s # <-- 
    "Song"
  end
end

class Songson < Song
  def to_s
    super + "<Songson>"
  end
end

song = Songson.new()
p song
```

Don't try to use HTML to format your code (or your text), simply select your code and hit the 1010 button above the text entry area.

Comment: You can trust the WYSIWYG buttons here! They actually work unlike most sites!

Comment: And you don't even have to trust them, you can also hit `Ctrl-K` instead!

Answer (score 3):

Please see the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

In this particular case, to get the <'s to work, you'll need to indent your code 4 spaces.